# mongodb-nodejs-driver, DeprecationWarning: collection.count is deprecated

Tags: mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I want to get the count of posts documents using:

```js
db.collection('posts').count()
```

But, I got a warning:

> DeprecationWarning: collection.count is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. Use collection.countDocuments or collection.estimatedDocumentCount instead

Here is my mongodb nodejs driver version:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "mongodb": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/mongodb": "^3.1.0",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "mocha": "^5.1.1",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.0",
    "tslint": "^5.10.0",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2"
  }
```

There is no `countDocuments` or `estimatedDocumentCount`  in `index.d.ts` file.

How can I solve this warning?

Comment: Is this right syntax? I think you have problem in your  query ,what is post inside bracket, if you want  to count anything on field , first you need to find then count for ex:db.collectionName.find({filedName : filedValue}).count()

Comment: of course it's a right syntax. You can test it in mongo shell.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As you figured out, starting from [MongoDB Node.JS driver v3.1](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/quick-start/quick-start/)  the `count()` method has been deprecated and will be replaced with :

- [Collection.countDocuments()](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#countDocuments)
- [Collection.estimatedDocumentCount()](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#estimatedDocumentCount)

These methods have been added to [node-mongodb-native](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native)  package itself. For example, via the MongoDB Node.JS driver you should be able to do:

```
db.collection("posts").countDocuments(
  {}, // filters
  {}, // options
  function(error, result) {
    console.log(result);
  }
);
```

See also [NODE-1501](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-1501)

> There is no countDocuments or estimatedDocumentCount in index.d.ts file.

This is because the TypeScript definitions for the `mongodb` npm package has not been updated to include the two new methods. The list of types is actually maintained separately by community via [DefinitelyTyped](http://definitelytyped.org/) (GitHub: [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped))

I have submitted a pull request [DefinitelyTyped #27008](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/27008) to add the new methods. Once approved and published you should be able to see the typed definitions.

Comment: Which one matches the original .count ? It's .countDocuments right?

Comment: @Anthony it’s the estimatedDocumentCount()

Answer (score 5):

The underlying mongodb driver has deprecated the .count() method.You should use .estimatedDocumentCount() or .countDocuments() instead.